# How do I know if setFetchBatchSize is working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm executing an NSFetchRequest with a NSFetchedResultsController. I set a fetchBatchSize of 5, and implement the proper delegate methods:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

And I make sure to set the delegate of my `fetchedResultsController` to `self`. However, I put a NSLog statement in all the above delegate methods, and none of them are getting called. My `fetchRequestController` fetch count is 204, and the batch size is 5, so isn't it supposed to be calling some of the delegate methods as I scroll down the table? Or what's another way to make sure it's working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use fast enumeration on the fetchedObjects array of the fetchedResultsController and test the `isFault` property of each NSManagedObject. If you only asked for it to return 5, I think you should see that 5 have isFault set to NO and the rest have isFault set to YES.

See the [NSManagedObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) for info on the isFault property.

Answer (score 1):

A fetch controller should know how many managedobject are in total. I don't know where you are checking, but that could be the reason of your 204.
Also, those methods are getting called only when you modify the objects in your uitable datasource, they have nothing to do with the scrolling of the table itself.